# After a while (>15 minutes) i got HTTP status 500. (JSP pages)

Tags: java, jsp

i have jsp pages which uses some methods that i have developped to get data from some classes. Everything is working well! 
**BUT**
if try to use the pages after a while ( i dont know how much..) i get an error

> HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /units_central.jsp at line 36
>   **exception:** org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /units_central.jsp at line 36

The code is this

> line 32: <% UserBean currentUser = (UserBean)(session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser"));%>
>       line 33:  <% EducationalUnit units = new EducationalUnit();%>
>       line 34:  <% EducationalTopic topics = new EducationalTopic();%>
>       line 35:  <% int choice=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("param"));%>
>       line 36:   <%= units.getTitle(choice) %>User: <%= currentUser.getUsername() %>

the getTitle(int i) and the getUsername are methods that return a string.
the log file from Tomcat is this:

> Stacktrace:] with root cause
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at org.apache.jsp.units_005fcentral_jsp._jspService(units_005fcentral_jsp.java:108)
>   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain. > ja>va:305)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.
>   java:210)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.
>   java:1023>)
>   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol. > java:589)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Comment: What is `units` ? From where do you get it ?

Comment: @The New Idiot i do it! thx!

Comment: units is an object i create in line 33

Comment: Just inspect the line number 108 of the generated Servlet class `units_005fcentral_jsp.java`.

Comment: Under `{Tomcat_dir}/work/catalina/{webproject}/..`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33954/discussion-between-yaylitzis-and-the-new-idiot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method was returning null, thats why i had that error. After a while the session was expired, thats why.